# django-haystack more_like_this returns nothing

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I've installed the haystack app and I'm using the solr backend. Search works perfectly although when I try to use the more_like_this template tag, nothing is returned.

I have added `<requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler" />` to solrconfig.xml and I can make queries at http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/mlt

The template is fairly basic

```
{% load more_like_this %}
{% more_like_this video as related_videos limit 5 %}
{{ related_videos }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that mlt was pretty picky, I had to improve my indexing templates to get good mlt results.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, what do you mean "improve my indexing templates"?